# UITableView inside of a UITableView (UITableViewCell)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

**Scenario**

I have an app lets users post and those posts show up in a UITableView. Other user's will have the ability to comment on other users posts. So I want to add another UITableView to display the comments for each post.

**Just to recap**

Thats a UITableView that contains a UITableViewCell, and it is *that* UITableViewCell that will contain the another UITableView. Actually PFTableViewCell because I'm using the parse.com framework, but all the same.

(It gets me really confused thinking about it myself. Which is where I come to the next part.)

**Problem**

I am really not sure how to be thinking about this. It's like one of those house of mirrors and each mirror is looking at another mirror and creates and illusion of never ending hallway of confusion.

I have gotten to about here...

```
//the "top" view controller

-(PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    //I do all of my cell config here
    PostTableViewCell *cell;

    /* THIS IS WHERE IM LOST!
       In the "cell" I just made I have a UITableView set up
       with the delegate methods and everything, including
       an NSArray property called "comments". So, am I 
       supposed to do something like this?...
    */

    //Query for Comments
    PFQuery *commentsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
    [commentsQuery whereKey:@"parentID" equalTo:object.objectId];
    [commentsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [commentsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        /* maybe?
        [cell.commentTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.commentTableView numberOfRowsInSection:objects.count];
         */

        cell.comments = objects;

        /* And then in the PostTableViewCell file in it's
           table view methods am I supposed to use the
           "comments" property as the data source? If so, I
           have not been able to successfully do this it NSLogs
           "(null)"
        */

    }];

}
```

**Summary*

So as you can see, just by the fact I asked the "maybe?" comment in that pseudo code, I am really lost in try this out. I of course would love it all to be just coded out for me, but I would also appreciate if someone could just explain to me the process of achieving this. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're trying to do something that can get really messy. Do you have a limit on comment depth -- i.e. can a user comment on a comment that was a comment on another comment? I think you'd be better off just managing your data better and using a single `UITableView` with multiple styles of custom `UITableViewCell`s to accomplish this.

Comment: No there wasn't going to be the comment on a comment depth to it. But what do you mean better off with multiple styles of custom UITableViewCells?

Comment: Make two custom cells, one for the original post, and one for the comment. Your comment cell could have a different layout/style.  Or maybe look into using a `UICollectionView`.